# Accessing variables within a URL

Tags: c#, asp.net, variables

I have created a website where settings can be changed for the Language and Country which in turn change the url i.e. /en/ becomes /fr/ for French language.

I have everything working except for when the URL has variables attached. I am using a uri

```
Uri requestUrl
string queryValue = requestUrl.Query;
```

This is then passed into amethod which combines everything i need to return the requested url.

```
string actualUrl = GetActualUrl(GetUrlToRewrite(requestUrl), queryValue);
```

However using the queryValue string only gets populated with the first variable for example if my url to begin with was

```
sitepage.aspx?variable1=a&variable2=b
```

the string variable will only be populated with

```
?variable1=a
```

when i need

```
?variable1=a&variable2=b
```

**How do i go about filling one string declaration with both variables or two declarations with a variable each...i don't mind either way???????**

Comment: Need to see the code for `GetActualUrl()` and `GetUrlToRewrite()` to answer the question.

Comment: ... not to mention what you are setting `requestUrl` to (is it `Request.Url`?). But essentially you want `Request.Url.PathAndQuery`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ammended this question through the quesry string having "&" the system thought it was the end of the querystring. I chnged this by encoding and decoding my urls with **UrlEncode** and **UrlDecode**